# current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block - PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, unit-testing, transactions

```
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

What is the root cause for this error?

I have insert() and insertMany() function in Table.php and I am writing php unit test cases for both.

insert() function calls insertMany() internally. The difference being is insert() meant for accepting  single array and insertMany() for multiple arrays. I begin transaction, do insert operation and commit if result is good else I do rollback.

PHPUnit is failing to test insert() & insertMany() functions together. It gives me below error message if both test functions are executed:

```
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

However, if I comment either of the test functions it works fine. Also, it doesn't throw any errors when I comment transaction commands like BEGIN, COMMIT & ROLLBACK.

I have tried searching for this error but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Could any one at least tell me what might be a reason causing this problem?

Comment: or it has to do anything with isolation levels?

Comment: You should put the code of your functions.